# El significado de "ya verás tú cuando se puto muera"

Tags: significado

Según este [enlace](https://www.google.com/amp/s/cadenaser.com/ser/2020/07/23/television/1595494375_061891.amp.html), "ya verás tú cuando se puto muera" significa que alguien verá la muerte próxima de ‘x’ cosa. O sea, ¿la persona que dice esta oración está diciendo que alguien va a morir cuando ocurra 'x' cosa dentro de poco? ¿Podrían por favor ayudarme a entender la oración?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta imagen contiene lo más relevante del contenido enlazado

[image: Consulta y Respuesta a la RAE a través de Twitter]

No, el community manager de la RAE no está ratificando la interpretación de ese usuario de la frase. Se limita a explicar el significado y la grafía recomendada para el elemento "puto" en la frase.

Podemos eliminar dicho elemento de la frase pues no aporta al significado más que un rasgo intensificador y malsonante:

> Ya verás tú cuando se muera.

La frase está bien estructurada. No así la pregunta original, que contiene varias erratas.
Debería ser:

> La oración "ya verás tú cuando se puto muera" para referi**r**se
> **a que** alguien verá la muerte próxima de **una** cosa, ¿está bien
> estructurada?.

Desconocemos el contexto donde se ha empleado esa frase. Dado que el usuario Ulises indica que se trata de una cosa, descartamos que la muerte aceche a una persona. Hagamos un ejercicio de imaginación y planteemos un supuesto escenario. Imaginemos que la persona A está regando en demasía un cactus (la cosa) y la persona B le advierte del riesgo de realizar esa acción (regar).

> Deja de regarlo tanto. Ya verás tú cuando se (puto) muera.

**La frase en cuestión puede emplearse para censurar una acción realizada por el otro interlocutor o una tercera persona cuyos efectos pueden resultar mortales.**

Otro ejemplo podría ser:

> Estás cebando al hamster, le das demasiada comida. Ya verás tú cuando se (puto) muera

En resumen, la frase es una advertencia para indicarle a alguien que deje de realizar una acción si no quiere arrepentirse de ello en el futuro, pues la muerte no tiene vuelta atrás.

Podriamos reescribirla

> Al final (la cosa) se va a (puto) morir y te arrepentirás.

De todas formas, estoy de acuerdo con lo que apunta DGaleano en los comentarios, la frase suena extraña. Como él apunta, probablemente la original fuera:

> Ya verás cuando **e**se puto muera.

Por lo que nos llega a España, el sustantivo "puto" se usa bastante en México.

Comment: Esta explicación está bien, pero a mi la frase original me suena muy rara. Para mi simplemente falta una letra y la frase es muy fácil de entender. Pienso que la frase debería ser "Ya verás tu cuando **e**se puto muera"

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!

Comment: @Maurice de nada. De todas formas, estoy de acuerdo con DGaleano, la frase en si suena extraña. Probablemente sea la que él apunta: "Ya verás cuando ese puto muera."

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de RubioRic me parece correcta, pero no es la única interpretación posible. La expresión "ya verás" se usa para advertir al interlocutor sobre las inminentes consecuencias o repercusiones de un evento, ya sean positivas o negativas. Por ejemplo:

> Si el libro X te parece aburrido, ya verás cuando llegues al tercer capítulo.

Esta frase expresa que algo ocurrirá en el tercer capítulo, y que el interlocutor debería prepararse para ello. Evidentemente, no tiene la implicación de que las acciones del interlocutor vayan a tener un efecto sobre lo que ocurra en el libro.

La frase que has puesto como ejemplo puede parafrasearse como:

> Prepárate para cuando se muera.

> Cuando se muera, va a pasar algo grave.

Dependiendo del contexto, puede servir como advertencia para que el interlocutor actúe o deje de actuar de una determinada manera, pero eso está más allá del significado de "ya verás".

Por otra parte, lo que ocurra cuando se muera el objeto o la persona a la que se refiera el tweet puede ser algo bueno o malo. Lo más lógico es pensar que va a ser algo malo, pero podría no ser así. Por ejemplo:

> Fulanito ha sido siempre un cabrón sin escrúpulos y un sádico. Pero ya verás cuando se puto muera: nos vamos a forrar con su herencia.

Para saber a qué se refiere exactamente el twitero, habría que conocer mejor el contexto.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su interpretación !